# Have multiple views in one Window (MVVM)

Tags: mvvm, view

I'm trying to learn MVVM and as a new person without a tutor, sometimes it gets sooo confusing. right now I have this problem:

** in one window, I have used 3 different views from different modelviews.
** each view is for selecting one item from a branch and we will traverse the tree.
** in first View, I choose my book
** the 2nd view will show pages of that book
** the last view I want it to show exercises of that page.

so far I was able to bind the 1st view to the Books. now, how should I bind the second view's source to the 1st one's **slectedItem** ?

[MVVM Problem http://clickasun.ir/8283kitchen/images/mvvmproblem.jpg](http://clickasun.ir/8283kitchen/images/mvvmproblem.jpg)

Comment: it would be great if someone can provide me with a link to a sample application.

Comment: This might go into your direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599802/concrete-examples-of-state-sharing-between-multiple-viewmodels-wpf-mvvm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I want to thank anyone who read this and tried to help, Specially yo guys "Blindmeis, Jen H"

thank you.

I know this scenario had to be so general, I just couldnt find it.

so I found 2 approaches to it that both can be good solutions.

1. Use Microsoft Prism. (Its a pattern to make modular programs in WPF with ease)
    [MSDN LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx) 
    [Another LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc785479.aspx)
2. Use Master Detail Pattern
    [Here it is clear](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742531.aspx)

So I got mine solved. Hope it would be useful for you too.

Answer (score 1):

there are several ways to achieve what you want. eg.

```
 public class Exercise{}

 public class Page 
 {
    public List<Exercise> MyExercise {get;set;}
 }

 public class Book
 {
    public List<Page > MyPages {get;set;}
 }
```

viewmodel

```
 public ObservableCollection<Book> MyBooks {get;set;}
```

xaml

```
 <ListBox x:Name=books ItemsSource="{Binding MyBooks}"/>
 <ListBox x:Name=pages ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=books,Path=SelectedItem}"/>
 <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=pages,Path=SelectedItem}"/>
```

this is of course just one way to do it.

ps: code handwritten, so check for errors